# Doesn't running xorg with `needs_root_rights=yes` create a security risk?

Tags: permissions, xorg

I am trying to get xpra running using the Xdummy driver and in following the examples on https://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Xdummy I tried the example there with this command. I suspect that it starts on a separate display because of the `:10` at the end because it is not an example with attaches to an exiting `xpra` display.

```
Xorg -noreset +extension GLX +extension RANDR +extension RENDER -logfile ./10.log -config ./xorg.conf :10
```

The first instance resulted in the error `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server` which I fixed by changing `allowed_users=console` to `allowed_users=anybody` in `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.conf`.

The second trial resulted in the error:

```
Fatal server error:                                              
(EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)
```

Some web searching resulted in the suggestion to add `needs_root_rights=yes` to `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.conf` which enabled it to work.

Because the error message stated `parse_vt_settings` I tried add `-novtswitch` from the xorg man page (whose meaning I don't understand) to the command invocation but that made no difference. `needs_root_rights` was required.

Doesn't `needs_root_rights=yes` create a security risk?

Comment: I believe you should read https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-Xwrapper/ as far I can understand newer Linux versions use wrappers here and there, for security measures. This setting removes that security and if someone could elaborate further on this I also would like to find a better answer to this question. It seems to me Xorg is opened up again on the system which is something linux users are warned for that Xorg is not secure by itself.

Comment: to get access to `/dev/tty0` add yourself to the `tty` group. Do NOT go around giving everything root privileges. In general, when you get permission issues, use `ls -l` to find the group the "file"* belongs to and assign it to yourself. On UNIX, everything is a file ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. But you don't need to do that.

You're using the wrong `Xorg`, on most Ubuntu versions you should be using `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg`, Debian and other distros may use a slightly different path.
(the one you tried to use is `/usr/bin/Xorg` which is just a script, which calls another script... and eventually calls the correct Xorg binary)